# zeit now with flask + telegram

Tags: flask, telegram-bot, vercel

I am using https://zeit.co (free) and was thinking setup a webhook for telegram chat bot.

I sent a message from the telegram app on the phone and it supposes to post a json to the webhook url. It does post the data but i cannot get the json. It seems zeit.co cannot handle the json?

It is like something stuck whenever i tried to call `request.json`

```
@app.route("/new_message", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def telegram_webhook_handler():
    try:
        print(request.json)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            r = request.get_json()
            chat_id = r['message']['chat']['id']
            text = "how are you?"
            send_message(CHAT_ID, text)

        else:
            send_message(CHAT_ID, "This is a get")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

    return jsonify({"ping": "pong"})
```

The error message from zeit.co

12/27 01:42 PM (40s)
REPORT RequestId: 3462880b-09d4-11e9-b07e-77492ad19973  Duration: 300021.80 ms  Billed Duration: 300000 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 42 MB
12/27 01:42 PM (40s)
2018-12-27T12:42:42.838Z 3462880b-09d4-11e9-b07e-77492ad19973 Task timed out after 300.02 seconds

Any idea how i can get the webhook data?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Your code has exceeded its duration limit.

```
Duration: 300021.80 ms Billed Duration: 300000 ms
```

If you want to increase the duration limit, you will have to [upgrade](https://zeit.co/account/plan) your Zeit account.

Comment: Well you might think so but in this case, no. It a simple task, should be 1 sec max! I moved to Heroku and wirh same code, no problem at all. So, it not the code issue, rather Zeit cannot  handle post for some reason.

Comment: It says very clearly in the error that the runtime limit was exceeded. It had to be something wrong with your code. I am fairly certain that zeit can handle a POST request.

Comment: well yes, it's because this line request.get_json() took more than 30 seconds. I got a response from  Zeit about alpha-stage, so it could be something they need to fix. Also, if the code is not OK, it would be same error on Heroku don't you think?

Comment: There is no error Heroku because it seems that they have an increased runtime limit. Around 30 seconds. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#router

Comment: As i am saying, the code executes within 1 second on my dev and on heroku. With zeit, it ran over 30secs and timeout. I am not sure why you keep saying it's a timeout-thing? If it executes fast and both machines but not Zeit, would you say i am wrong about Zeit? Did you test Flask on Zeit with my code? Anyway, i maybe tried Zeit in the future, but not now!

Comment: I am saying it a timeout error because I know for sure it is. It clearly says in the error message you gave, the `task timed out` because it exceeded its runtime limit. Why it does not happen on Heroku, I am not sure, but I am willing to bet you changed your code in some way. You could have even improperly configured your Zeit project